# Python Negative Indexing

Tags: python

I know that negative indexing in Python selects elements starting from the back of the list, but is there some way of specifying elements in a python list that I *don't want*?

```
> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
> print(x[(-2,-3)])
> [1,2,5]
```

Comment: [e for e in my_list if e not in to_exclude]

Comment: If `to_exclude` is a `set` you'll get `O(N)` performance.

Comment: @Blckknght -- If it's a list or tuple you'll get O(N * M) -- since `N` (the number of items to exclude) is likely to be much smaller than `M` (the total number of items), it probably doesn't make that much of a difference in your algorithm's scaling (it's basically a small constant factor which is omitted in bit-O analysis).  That said, for big lists, small constant factors can still make a big difference for overall runtime ...

Comment: There are a lot of solutions if you're using numpy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429118/how-to-get-all-the-values-from-a-numpy-array-excluding-a-certain-index

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a good way to do that.  Usually, I'll use a set with a comprehension:

```
[item for i, item in enumerate(lst) if i not in {2, 3}]
```

Using a `set` in this context is pretty important (especially as the number of indices that you want to omit grows) because it has O(1) membership testing.  Frequently you'll see `list` or `tuple` used in this context where membership testing is O(N) on average.

---

Note: If you aren't on python3.2+, you'll probably want to define the set first as earlier python versions will re-create the set for each iteration of the loop:

```
omit_please = {2, 3}
[item for i, item in enumerate(lst) if i not in omit_please]
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `if i not in...`?

Comment: @AlexHall -- Yep.  Sorry.  I was too busy trying to figure out when python's peephole optimizer started turning `set` into `frozenset` in this sort of scenario to notice the bug.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Also, could use set subtraction if you liked the notation more, but it would be the same solution. +1