# How to select all elements in a NumPy array except for a sequence of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have some long array and a list of indices. How can I select everything except those indices? I found a solution but it is not elegant:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0,10,20,30,40,50,60])
exclude = [1, 3, 5]
print x[list(set(range(len(x))) - set(exclude))]
```

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429118/how-to-get-all-the-values-from-a-numpy-array-excluding-a-certain-index

Comment: @AlperFıratKaya, your link removes just one element, not a list of them.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This is what [`numpy.delete`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) does. (It doesn't modify the input array, so you don't have to worry about that.)

```
In [4]: np.delete(x, exclude)
Out[4]: array([ 0, 20, 40, 60])
```

Answer (score 28):

`np.delete` does various things depending what you give it, but in a case like this it uses a mask like:

```
In [604]: mask = np.ones(x.shape, bool)
In [605]: mask[exclude] = False
In [606]: mask
Out[606]: array([ True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
In [607]: x[mask]
Out[607]: array([ 0, 20, 40, 60])
```

Comment: The best solution and one that I assume is the most vectorizable and efficient.

Comment: @JoeyCarson, can you please explain why it's better than accepted one?

Comment: @ShihabShahriarKhan According to [numpy.delete](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) documentation, "Often it is preferable to use a boolean mask ... [It] is equivalent to np.delete(...), but allows further use of mask."

Answer (score 9):

`np.in1d` or `np.isin` to create boolean index based on `exclude` could be an alternative:

```
x[~np.isin(np.arange(len(x)), exclude)]
# array([ 0, 20, 40, 60])

x[~np.in1d(np.arange(len(x)), exclude)]
# array([ 0, 20, 40, 60])
```

Comment: This has the advantage of being usable in assignment. Still, wondering if there isn't something more efficient...

Answer (score -1):

You can also use a list comprehension for the index

```
>>> x[[z for z in range(x.size) if not z in exclude]]
array([ 0, 20, 40, 60])
```