# What is the easiest way in NumPy to index vectors of a matrix excluding one index in each row?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a NumPy ndarray M with the following content at `M[0,:]`:

```
[2, 3.9, 7, 9, 0, 1, 8.1, 3.2]
```

and I am given an integer, k, at runtime between 0 and 7. I want to produce the vector consisting of all items in this row except at column k. (Example: if k=3, then the desired vector is [2,3.9,7,0,1,8.1,3.2])

Is there an easy way to do this?

What if I have a vector of indices k, one for each row of M, representing the column I want to exclude from the row?

I'm kind of lost, other than a non-vectorized loop that mutates a result matrix:

```
nrows = M.shape[0]
result = np.zeros(nrows,M.shape[1]-1))
for irow in xrange(nrows):
    result[irow,:k[irow]] = M[irow,:k[irow]]   # content before the split point
    result[irow,k[irow]:] = M[irow,k[irow]+1:] # content after the split point
```

Comment: [another question is close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286657/index-all-except-one-item-in-python), but it's 1D, and this involves 2D, so it's not an exact duplicate.

Comment: [another question that is also 1D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429118/how-to-get-all-the-values-from-a-numpy-array-excluding-a-certain-index)... to those of you marking as possible duplicates, did you read this question carefully? there are so many well-meaning attempts at "improvements" on this site that are a bit hasty.

Comment: vaguely related to the inverse problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074422/select-one-element-in-each-row-of-a-numpy-array-by-column-indices

Comment: **Please read this / other questions carefully before marking as a duplicate.**

Comment: Please reopen, this is different from the nominated question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429118/how-do-i-get-all-the-values-from-a-numpy-array-excluding-a-certain-index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be with [`masking`/`boolean-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) -

```
mask = np.ones(M.shape,dtype=bool)
mask[np.arange(len(k)),k] = 0
out = M[mask].reshape(len(M),-1)
```

Alternativley, we could use `broadcasting` to get that `mask` -

```
np.not_equal.outer(k,np.arange(M.shape[1]))
# or k[:,None]!=np.arange(M.shape[1])
```

Thus, giving us a one-liner/compact version -

```
out = M[k[:,None]!=np.arange(M.shape[1])].reshape(len(M),-1)
```

---

To exclude multiple ones per row, edit the advanced-indexing part for the first method -

```
def exclude_multiple(M,*klist):
    k = np.stack(klist).T
    mask = np.ones(M.shape,dtype=bool)
    mask[np.arange(len(k))[:,None],k] = 0
    out = M[mask].reshape(len(M),-1)
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [185]: M = np.arange(40).reshape(4,10)

In [186]: exclude_multiple(M,[1,3,2,0],[4,5,8,1])
Out[186]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29],
       [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]])
```

Comment: Thanks, your numpy-fu far exceeds mine. Which of those methods would you expect to be more performant for large arrays?

Comment: @JasonS I would go with the first one for being memory efficient and hopefully should translate to perf.

Comment: any comment about using `mask[xrange(len(k)),k]` vs. `mask[np.arange(len(k)),k]`?

Comment: @JasonS I would use `np.arange`. Arrays work better.

Comment: i'd love to read a blog post about all this stuff. hard to predict what's going to happen until you try a bunch of things :/

Comment: @JasonS True, you learn about those mostly by using them and trying out various tools. Can't think of any but the official docs for some info into those.

Comment: based on your answer, i just added an improvement to exclude more than one element from each row

Comment: @JasonS Added solution for the multiple ones.

Answer (score 1):

Improvement on @Divakar's answer to extend this to zero or more excluded indices per row:

```
def excluding(A, *klist):
    """ 
    excludes column k from each row of A, for each k in klist 
    (make sure the index vectors have no common elements)
    """
    mask = np.ones(A.shape,dtype=bool)
    for k in klist:
        mask[np.arange(len(k)),k] = 0
    return A[mask].reshape(len(A),-1)
```

Test:

```
M = np.arange(40).reshape(4,10)
excluding(M,[1,3,2,0],[4,5,8,1])
```

returns

```
array([[ 0,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29],
       [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]])
```